# Prometheus Windows Exporter System Reserved Disk Exclusion

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I was wondering if you are able to advise on a query;

I have the following query which illustrates the free disk percentage for each windows volume

```
100 - (100 - 100 * (windows_logical_disk_free_bytes / windows_logical_disk_size_bytes))
```

The issue I face is that it returns all volumes including system reserverd volumes (Hardisk volume 1)

"windows_exporter_metrics",volume="C:"}

**"windows_exporter_metrics",volume="HarddiskVolume1"}"**

Does anyone know how to tailor this so that system reserved volumes are omitted? Previously I had the query focused on a single volume C: but this omits other valid volumes.

```
expr: 100-(100 - 100 * (windows_logical_disk_free_bytes{volume="C:"} / windows_logical_disk_size_bytes{volume="C:"}))
```

Please note i have asked this question on the Prometheus forum but hadn't received a reply.

Appreciate any advice / guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out how to do this for my own requirement.

For anyone that is interested please see below.

```
100-(100 - 100 * (windows_logical_disk_free_bytes{volume=~".:"} / windows_logical_disk_size_bytes{volume=~".:"}))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the below for accurate percentage of Drives. this works

```
100 -(windows_logical_disk_free_bytes{volume=~".:"} / windows_logical_disk_size_bytes{volume=~".:"}) * 100
```